# Bigcommerce Simple Click App in getting products

Tags: php, api, authentication, response, bigcommerce

I'm a beginner in using Bigcommerce API and I have done Auth callback and load callback successfully. My question is how do I get the products in my app store? I just have a client_id and client_secret do I really need to use Legacy API account like using the username and api key or is there anyway i can just use my app client id and client secret in getting some data from bigcommerce. What is the use of signed_payload?